# XAML Edit & Continue broken on VS2017 v15.7.1?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I've installed VS15.7.1 Create a dummy UWP project targeting Build 10240. 
With this configuration:
[image]

Execute the app.
Modify the text inside a button in the XAMl in VS.
Nothing gets reflect in the running app.

This used to work before. It's any kind of hidden setting or it's broken?

[image]
[image]

I I target version 1803 as in the photo XAML Edit & Continue works, but In 10240 it's broken:

[image]

Comment: What  a *dummy UWP* project you mean here? Could you please tell more?

Comment: Create a normal UWP project targeting 10240. Put a button on the MainPage with content "Hi I'm a button". Press F5. Modify the content while running to "Hi I'm a button 5". See how it's not being modified while running unless you Debug it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was finally a bug in Visual Studio that is going to be fixed soon in VS 2018 preview 3: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/256287/xaml-edit-continue-broken-in-uwp-10240.html

Comment: This problem was resolved in 15.8, but if anything seems broken in the future please let us know. thank you for helping make Visual Studio better!